# sending data between two devices in android

Tags: android, database

Is it possible to send database from one device to other.Suppose consider i am using one application in device1,and now i am installing the same application in other device(device2). Now is it possible to send that database from device1 to device2>Is any option for that except Google cloud.

Comment: in what way SMS,Bluetooth,Wifi or any other way ?

Comment: @hotveryspicy , sending via SMS,Bluetooth or WiFi doesn't require Server

Comment: I am guessing that he is asking apart from this. @Lucifer

Comment: agree with you, @hotveryspicy, but your answer was uncomplete

Comment: Anyway but without server.If suppose through bluetooth how can i send,also give some links or tutorials about sending database between two devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirements, there are 5 possible ways to send-receive data between two Android Devices,

- SMS [Send](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sending-sms-from-application/)-[Receive](http://webhole.net/2011/09/28/android-sdk-tutorial-how-to-receive-text-messages/)
- [Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)
- [WiFi](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html)
- [Web-Service](http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html)
- [C2DM](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

Comment: Lucifer if i had some problem i will get u back.I think i will surely get problem.

Comment: sure, i am here till office hours.